# Sending json data to php web service

Tags: php, jquery, json, web-services

I am sending to the server this call:

```
var Message = {};
Message['islands'] = '1-15-13';
Message['newMessageText'] = 'this is test message';
$.ajax({
    url: "sendnote.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: Message,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data["result"]);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert(data["result"]);
    }
});
```

and on server (sendnote.php) I have

```
print_r($_POST);
```

just to check do I receive anything, but after cchecking response in Firebug I see that this array is empty.

What am I doing wrong in sending data?

Thanks in advance!

PS I've checked previous post on this subject, but still have problems with it.

Comment: Hmm, how did you get data["result"]? Is there more to the sendnote.php script that you are not showing? Or is it just print_r($_POST)?

Comment: When I run that code, I can see the data being POSTed.

Comment: Quentin, you are right, I see that too, but in Firebug I see that my $_POST is empty. That's the problem. That's why I did just print_r($_POST)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the contentType

Try this:

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var Message = {};
    Message['islands'] = "1-15-13";
    Message['newMessageText'] = 'this is test message';

$.ajax({
        url: "sendnote.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: Message,
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data) {
            alert("Islands: "+data.islands+", Message: "+data.newMessageText);
            },
        error:function(data) {
            alert('error');
        }  });
});
```

php

```
<?php
    echo json_encode($_POST);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`print_r($_POST)` does not give a JSON response. do you even know what the actual reply of the request looks like when not using AJAX?

try `echo json_encode($_POST);` - this should print out a valid JSON.

or might i add that you might have forgotten PHP's `<?php ?>` opening and close tags

Comment: I think he's checking the ajax request in Firebug. But yeah, I think you are right if sendnote.php is just print_r($POST);

Comment: Gohn67, you are right. I am just checking $_POST in Firebug. I have in my code $jsonresponse = json_encode($_POST) and other code which creates JSON response. On the client side I receive JSON response that is obviously result of empty $_POST.