# How to convert an array in PHP into a valid JSON request and send it to web service URL in following scenario?

Tags: php, arrays, json, web-services

I've got following array titled $val in PHP :

```
Array
(
    [page_id] => 208
    [invite_emails] => 
    [invite] => Array
        (
            [0] => 970
            [1] => 991
            [2] => 992
        )

)
```

I only want to convert the above array into a valid JSON request and send it to some web service URL.

How should I do it? Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert php array into single JSON object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432914/convert-php-array-into-single-json-object)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather broad, but to convert a php array into a JSON object is very easy.

```
$jsonString = json_encode($array);
```

As for sending it to the URL, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884340/sending-json-data-to-php-web-service) contains some good info.

Or if you want to use curl, [this](http://thisinterestsme.com/sending-json-via-post-php/) resource is pretty good.

Comment: But how could I get as an argument in my WS? Suppose following is the request pattern $application->get('/sendInvitation(/:val)','authorization', function()
val must be the array in JSON format.

Answer (score 1):

As others have posted, use the following to json encode your array:

```
json_encode($val);
```

Now, your problem is sending this to your web service via parameter. The way I generally send complex parameters via GET parameters is by base64 encoding.

```
$param = base64_encode(json_encode($val));
```

Now you can send $param just like any other parameter. Take a look at [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) for making HTTP requests from PHP.

Comment: @PHPLover Second the Guzzle recommend. Dont mess about with cURL or similar your life will be immeasurably improved by using a decent client library and I think Guzzle is the best